# Help with haskell rotate code

Tags: haskell

Ok so i know this is slightly wrong but what am i missing in it? The code is to rotate individual letters in words like:

```
rotate 1   "hello" "ohell"  
rotate -1  "hello" "elloh"
```

The code i have is:

```
module Main where

import System

main = do  
        (arg1:_) <- getArgs  
        xs <- getContents  
        putStr  (rotate xs arg1)  

rotate input w1 = unlines [ process line | line <- lines input ]  
        where process line = unwords [ word | word <- words line ]  
         map rotate n xs = drop n xs ++ take n xs
```

Is any of this right so far and any clue/tips where to go next?

So a bit more like this:

```
shift :: a -> Int -> a
rotate :: a -> Int -> a

 x shift i   | i<0       = x shiftR (-i)
             | i>0       = x shiftL i
             | otherwise = x

 x rotate  i | i<0       = rotateR (-i)
             | i>0       = rotateL i
             | otherwise = x
```

Comment: 1. You need to format this code.  2. what is the definition of `f` used in the `process` function? 3. Why are you redefining `map`?  You don't even use the new definition of `map`.  4. Detailed subjects are good - 'help with haskell' doesn't say anything the tags don't already tell me.

Comment: I did not notice the f was there as it wasnt sposed to be. In reference to the map i dont fully understand what you mean, i'm new to haskell. Thanks

Comment: I'd start with separating positive and negative cases of shift, because they have different recursion steps. Think pattern matching, forget the imperative style. The code to rotate elements of a list can be much simpler and use no `do` at all.

Comment: @9000, anon1:  Don't treat them separately, just add the length of the list to the negative case, thus making it positive (and semantically equivalent); writing two separate rotations is just ugly.  Notice: `rotate -1 hello --> elloh` and `rotate 4 hello --> elloh`

Comment: I do not want to spoil it for you, but look at the following functions: mod, last, init, length.

Answer (score 20):

### The Quick answer:

Try this:

```
rotate :: Int -> [Char] -> [Char]
rotate x st = take (length st) $ drop (negate x `mod` length st) $ cycle st
```

It yields:

```
rotate (1) "hello"
>>> "ohell"
rotate (-1) "hello"
>>> "elloh"
```

---

### The Explanation:

The insight needed for this to work, is knowledge of the `cycle` function, which repeats a string forever.

```
cycle "ezra"
>>> "ezraezraezraezraezr..." (forever)
```

Using this knowledge, we can exploit `length`, `take`, and `drop` to give us the part of the string that we want.  We'll also use `negate` and `mod` for the math part.

---

#### length

`length` returns the length of the list (strings are lists of characters).

```
length "ezra"
>>> 4
```

---

#### take

`take n` returns the first `n` items in a list.

```
take 9 (cycle "ezra")
>>> "ezraezrae"
```

---

#### drop

`drop n` returns the whole list, except the first `n` elements.

```
drop 3 "ezra"
>>> "a"
drop 3 (take 9 (cycle "ezra"))
>>> "aezrae"
```

---

#### mod

Using the `mod` function, we can get the proper offsets.  The backticks ` make the function "infix", which makes it more understandable.  This is the "remainder" after the division, if you're not familiar with [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

```
10 `mod` 3
>>> 1
```

This will give us the starting point.

---

#### negate

`negate n` returns the negation of `n`, which we need to "reverse" the direction, and get the output you wanted.

```
negate 10
>>> -10
```

---

When we put it all together, we get the function above.  There are, of course, many ways to do this: this is one.

In my solution above, I developed it in in the following order.

1. Get the infinite list:

   ```
   rotate x st = cycle st
   ```
2. Take the right number of characters:

   ```
   rotate x st = take (length st) $ cycle st
   ```
3. Take the characters from the right position:

   ```
   rotate x st = take (length st) $ drop (x `mod` length st) $ cycle st
   ```

At this point I had what I wanted, but had to add `negate` so that my output would match yours.

I also added the type signature.  I like to have them explicit on as many of my functions as I can.

Comment: Seeing as this looked like homework I think providing the full answer is a bit much, but good work on the long explanation.

Comment: Thanks for that, it was a great help to creating my own version of this!